# Force Firefox to remember non-standard credentials

Tags: firefox

There are a few sites that force individuals to enter multiple passwords.

**NetScaler**

[image]

For some reason, FF will not store the `User name` value, but will store the `Password`.  I'd like FF to store the `User name`, too.

`Password 2` is a security code generated by Symantic's VIP Access OS X/Android application.  One can also supply `push`, which will ask the app for confirmation.  I'd like FF to store `push`.

**Delta**

[image]

Asks the individual to supply a `Last Name`.  I'd like FF to store this value, in addition to the `Username` and `Password`.

**Vizient (alliancewebs.net)**

[image]

[image]

Asks the individual to supply a `Username` on the first page, click next, then supply a `Password` on the second page.  I'd like FF to supply the `Password` on the second page.

Is there a way to fix any of these annoyances?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's rules (and those of many other browsers) for recognizing login forms are pretty basic, and will probably never cover these edge cases.

I would recommend using a password manager like [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) which, as well as having the advantage of being cross-platform and independent of your browser, can integrate with your browser using extensions like [Kee](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keefox/) (formerly KeeFox). When set up correctly, it will autofill login fields for websites as normal, as well as allow you to save new logins after you've typed them.

Where things change, though, is that this extension and the corresponding plugin for KeePass allow you to make advanced autofill rules that can fill anything you want into any field. It won't get everything right on the first try, but you can 'train' it, or edit it manually (there's detailed documentation on all of it).

Expressed visually:

KeePass + KeePassRPC plugin ⇄ Firefox + Kee add-on